# Fully Qualifid Domain Name vs Fully Qualified DNS Name vs DNS Name vs DNS Domain vs DNS Domain Name?

Tags: dns, fqdn

Fully Qualified Domain Name **vs.** Fully Qualified DNS Name **vs.** DNS Name **vs.** DNS Domain **vs.** DNS Domain Name?

Do they all mean FQDN?

Thanks.

Comment: hey guys, am I posting in wrong place? Let me know. Thanks. Not sure which stackoverflow is best. Cheers

Comment: Indeed, it is not really a programming question, so this is not the good place. unfortunately I can not see any relevant SE site for this. In short, all you say is basically synonyms out of context. There could be a difference between fully and non fully domain, like my host can be called `foobar` (that is NOT an FQDN) and it lives in domain `example.com`, so its FQDN is `foobar.example.com`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name and https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8499 for all definitions regarding domain names, including FQDN. Hope that helps.

Comment: hi @PatrickMevzek thanks, I got the answers from posting on sysadmin subreddit https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/hccwm9/domain_vs_domain_name_confusion/    and     https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/hbufxy/fully_qualify_domain_name_vs_fully_qualified_dns/

Comment: Up to you but I would probably prefer Wikipedia and an RFC over reddit. Since "FQDN = hostname + domain name" is just wrong as displayed over there. `gouv.fr` is an FQDN but `gouv` is certainly not an hostname there (there is no host called by that name). PS: Note that DN in DNS means Domain Name anyway... So DNS Name and DNS Domain and DNS Domain Name are just poor names(!) with useless repetition